# Laravel Eloquent disable automatic lazy loading

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Laravel by default has this automatic eager loading which may cause some multiple query issue Eg:

```
// If do something like this
$posts = Post::published()->get();
// then
foreach ($posts as $p) {
    echo $p->author->name;
}
// Eloquent will query the author for every post
```

Is it possible to disable this behavior?

Comment: here solution https://laravel-news.com/disable-eloquent-lazy-loading-during-development

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's pretty simple, just add to your model:

`public $preventsLazyLoading = true;`

Then if you try to lazy load a relation you will get an error

```
Illuminate\Database\LazyLoadingViolationException : Attempted to lazy load [<ModelName>] on model [<ModelName>] but lazy loading is disabled.
```

You can also create a parent class for your models, something like

```
abstract class Model extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{
    public $preventsLazyLoading = true;
}
```

Then extend it in your models and they automatically will disable lazy load.

**For Laravel 8 or later versions**

There's another way to disable it in app service provide

```
// app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php
 
public function boot()
{
    Model::preventLazyLoading(! app()->isProduction());
}
```

As it says, it will disable lazy load for all environments except production.

[Reference](https://laravel-news.com/disable-eloquent-lazy-loading-during-development)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, also 0 documentation about this... =(

Comment: d= (◕‿↼ ) Nice direct answer! But for anyone in furure, **see the [answer to main issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60310062/8740349)**, beside above which's what OP thought was the solution (see also [What is the XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Answer (score 6):

In the example you provided, the relationship data is "lazy loaded" not "eager loaded". This means the relationship data is not actually loaded until you first access the property.

However, Eloquent can "eager load" relationships at the time you query the parent model. Eager loading alleviates the N + 1 query problem.

To eager load a relationship, you can use eloquent `with()` method:

```php
$posts = Post::published()->with('author')->get();
```

Now each `post` will be eagger loaded with the `author` model, thus avoiding the N + 1 problem.

You can also specify if you would like to eager load specific columns only:

```php
$posts = Post::published()->with('author:id,name')->get();
```

And if you want to always load a relationship when retrieving a model, you can define a $with property on the model:

```php
class Post extends Model
{
    /**
     * The relationships that should always be loaded.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $with = ['author'];

    /**
     * Get the author that wrote the book.
     */
    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Author');
    }
}
```

More information: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: This is surely one of Laravel's most used feature.

Comment: d= (◕‿↼ ) Thanks for answering the X of OP's [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @LobsterBaz i've changed the title of the question from eager to lazy, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2):

It's lazy load the example you provided as @LobsterBaz mentioned. If you want to avoid that:

You can check if the relationship is loaded

```
foreach ($posts as $p) { 
    if ($p->relationLoaded('author')) echo $p->author->name; 
}
```

But I found this package [Laravel Disable Lazy Load](https://github.com/ybaruchel/laravel-disable-lazyload) which has all the credit for the idea.

That is very simple. By borrowing the idea you can create a Trait yourself to do it overriding the [getRelationshipFromMethod](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.html#method_getRelationshipFromMethod).

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;


trait DisableLazyLoad
{
    public function getRelationshipFromMethod($method)
    {
        throw new \BadMethodCallException('Relation lazy load has been disabled for performance reasons.');
    }
}
```

Then use the Trait in your Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Traits\DisableLazyLoad;

class Post extends Model
{

    use DisableLazyLoad;

}
```

or install the package an use it in the same way

```
composer require ybaruchel/laravel-disable-lazyload
```

Comment: Thats exactly what i need, in my opnion this is a feature that may lead us to a poor code where things "Magicaly happens" causing more problems than helping...
In this case the N + 1 query problem..
Oh and i found this https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-query-detector wich helps a lot

Comment: @NetoBraghetto for that purpose, I use sql logger. It prints all queries and also it can help you to find out if there's any hidden/redundant database call. https://github.com/mnabialek/laravel-sql-logger